# making a Pinterest layout

Tags: javascript, css

Im making a pinterest layout. and I'm in a trouble with vertical-spacings between figure and figure. every figure has different height. and the second line's images has the top-spacing. how could I remove the spacing?

```
  .columns{
    width:93%;
    margin-top:80px;                                                            
    column-gap:0px;
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
  }

  .columns .figure{
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-right:3px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:8px;
    border-radius:10px; 
    width:230px;
  }

  .columns .figure:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background: rgba(80,80,80,0.1);
  }

  .columns .figure img{
    width:230px;
    border-radius:10px;
  }

  .columns .figure p{
    margin-top:1px; 
    max-height:80px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    word-break:break-all;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:210px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbIav.jpg)

Comment: Please provide HTML code to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` (or something like [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)). 
Also, you can set your rows to be [equal height](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp).

```
.columns-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.columns {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 16px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the column class

```
.columns{
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  column-count: 4;
}
```

This will create four columns, however, your content will flow top to bottom in every column.

You can also control the spacing between columns using the following

```
.columns{
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2px;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 2px;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 2px;
}
```

Read more at this link https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp